# How to programmatically open my accordion menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I'm using a very simple jQuery accordion script but what I'd like to achieve is a way to programmatically open a menu item on page load.  Ultimately this will be when a user browses directly to a page within a submenu, that menu opens to identify where they are.  I just cannot figure out how to trigger the opening on load...  Any help appreciated.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JQuery navigation test 2</title>

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<style>

#nav {
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
}
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background: #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
#nav li a:hover, #nav li a.active {
    background: #999;
    color: #fff;
}
#nav li ul {
    display: none;
}
#nav li ul li a {
    padding: 10px 25px;
    background: #ececec;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 1 c</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="https://google.com">Link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 c</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 3 d</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 c</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
    <li><a href="https://google.com">Link 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
    else {
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
        $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
    }
  });

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually apply the active class to the element and then when document is ready slideToggle the element with *active* class. For instance:

In the HTML:

```
<li><a href="#" class="activate-on-load">Menu 3</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 a</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 b</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub-Item 4 c</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

And in the Javascript part:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
    else {
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
        $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
    }
  });

  var toActivate = $('.activate-on-load');
  toActivate.next().slideToggle();
  toActivate.addClass('active');

});
```

This should work.

What I'd also suggest is adding additional classes for those menu elements instead of using such complexed selectors.

Comment: thanks to all the suggestions - this is the one I went for though and it works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Just putting code within the `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` will make it run on load (once the document is ready). To open the correct accordion, you can use `window.location` to get your URL to determine what page the user is on and open the accordion accordingly.

This could be made easier by adding `id`s to your menus so you can easily select and open it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `location`or `pathname`(it's up to you) in order to compare your current page with your accordion `HREFs`.

[Here is an exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/w6za9sLq/)

Added JS:

```
var pagePath = window.location.pathname; // To be used
var splitedPath = pagePath.split("/"); //Split to match your href formating


//Find A tag that match your path, find its parent UL and the A tag before (the one which has click event);
$("#nav > li > ul > li > a[href='" + splitedPath[splitedPath.length - 1] + "']").closest("ul").prev("a").trigger("click");
```

---

- First get the location/pathname
- Split it in order to match your current href formating
- Select the parent A to simulate a click